# How to change the cursor style for based mode of neovim?

Tags: cursor, neovim, underline

I am beginner in neovim, I trying to customise my neovim configuration, so one of the first things that I wanna change is the cursor style, by default neovim offers a block cursor for base mode, but I prefer the underline, I have searched on the web and I don't fine much information about it, if you can help me with this, I will be very grateful.

I am trying to change the cursor style on neovim base mode from block to underline, I expecte fine a configuration for this or where can I fine more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

To change your cursor in Neovim, see help for `guicursor`: `:h guicursor`.

To change your cursor (block by default) to underline (horizontal line) for all modes: `set guicursor=a:hor20`.

If you prefer a cursor with a vertical line as shape: `set guicursor=a:ver20`